# Postgres Find missing dates between a dataset of two columns

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to create a query that retuns missing dates between two columns and multiple rows.

Example:
leases

```
move_in          move_out       hotel_id
2021-04-01    2021-04-14    1
2021-04-17   2021-04-30     1
2021-04-01    2021-04-14    2
2021-04-17   2021-04-30     2
```

Result should be

```
date         hotel_id
2021-04-15   1
2021-04-16   1
2021-04-15   2
2021-04-16   2
```

Comment: Do you want it to all of them? Or for a certain date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're finding the difference between two sets. One is the leased hotel days. The other is all days in the month of April. And you're doing this for all hotels.

We can make a set of all days of April for all hotels. First we need to build the set of all days in the month of April: `generate_series('2022-04-01'::date, '2022-04-30'::date, '1 day')`.

Then we need to cross join this with all hotel IDs.

```
select *
from generate_series('2021-04-01'::date, '2021-04-30'::date, '1 day') as dates(day)
cross join (
  select distinct hotel_id as id
  from leases
) as hotels(id)
```

Now for each day we can left join this with the leases for that day.

```
select *
from generate_series('2021-04-01'::date, '2021-04-30'::date, '1 day') as dates(day)
cross join (
  select distinct hotel_id as id
  from leases
) as hotels(id)
```

Any days without a lease won't have a `lease.id`, so filter on that.

```
select day, hotels.id
from generate_series('2021-04-01'::date, '2021-04-30'::date, '1 day') as dates(day)
cross join (
  select distinct hotel_id as id
  from leases
) as hotels(id)
left join leases on day between move_in and leases.move_out and hotel_id = hotels.id
where leases.id is null
order by hotels.id, day
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4dac7ad8b4696445f74bdbacb56446eb).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgresql 14+ you can use `multirange`s to do this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (
    "move_in"  DATE,
    "move_out" DATE,
    "hotel_id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
    ("move_in", "move_out", "hotel_id")
VALUES ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-14', '1')
     , ('2021-04-17', '2021-04-30', '1')
     , ('2021-05-03', '2021-05-30', '1')  -- added this as a test case
     , ('2021-04-01', '2021-04-14', '2')
     , ('2021-04-17', '2021-04-30', '2');
```

---

```
SELECT hotel_id, datemultirange(DATERANGE(MIN(move_in), MAX(move_out))) - range_agg(DATERANGE(move_in, move_out, '[]')) AS r
FROM t
GROUP BY hotel_id
```

returns

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|hotel_id|r                                                |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|2       |{[2021-04-14,2021-04-17)}                        |
|1       |{[2021-04-14,2021-04-17),[2021-04-30,2021-05-03)}|
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

---

If you want to have 1 row per day you can use `unnest` and `generate_series` to expand the `multirange`s:

```
WITH available_ranges AS(
    SELECT hotel_id, unnest(datemultirange(DATERANGE(MIN(move_in), MAX(move_out), '[]')) - range_agg(DATERANGE(move_in, move_out, '[]'))) AS r
    FROM t
    GROUP BY hotel_id
)
SELECT hotel_id, generate_series(lower(r), upper(r) - 1, '1 day'::interval)
FROM available_ranges
ORDER BY 1, 2
;
```

returns

```
+--------+---------------------------------+
|hotel_id|generate_series                  |
+--------+---------------------------------+
|1       |2021-04-15 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
|1       |2021-04-16 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
|1       |2021-05-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
|1       |2021-05-02 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
|2       |2021-04-15 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
|2       |2021-04-16 00:00:00.000000 +00:00|
+--------+---------------------------------+
```